# Using Gamma identity in $E[\mid Z\mid]$ derivation (Expected Value).

Tags: probability, statistics

While finding the Expected value of Z, the solution runs into the gamma identity. Can someone explain how to get there?

**Step 1:** Z square is X2 which is Gamma 1/2 , 1/2.

$E[\mid Z\mid = \sqrt{Z^2} = \sqrt{\chi^2} = \sqrt{\Gamma(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})}$

**Step 2:** Use Gamma PDF to get expected value:
$E[\sqrt{\Gamma(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})}] = \frac{\lambda^\alpha}{\Gamma(\alpha)}\int_{0}^{\infty}\lambda^{(\alpha+\frac{1}{2})-1}e^{-\lambda x}dx$
*Questions about 2:* Why is there a fraction to the left of the integral? Is that the pdf? i thought the pdf didn't have a fraction $\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{t-1} e^{-x}dx$

**Step 3:** Use gamma identity for the integral.
$ \frac{\lambda^\alpha}{\Gamma(\alpha)}\int_{0}^{\infty}\lambda^{(\alpha+\frac{1}{2})+1}e^{-\lambda x}dx = \frac{\lambda^\alpha}{\Gamma(\alpha)} \frac{\Gamma(\alpha+1/2)}{\lambda^{\alpha+1/2}}$
Questions about 3: What???? Where did $\frac{\Gamma(\alpha+1/2)}{\lambda^{\alpha+1/2}}$ come from??

Comment: All solved here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution#Probability_density_function